# How to use Implicit rule for Makefile with .cpp files?

Tags: c++, makefile

There is a Implicit rule in Makefiles for C++ files, that use .C or .cc extension. But I usually have the .cpp file extension for C++ source.

How to use the Implicit rule for Makefile with .cpp files?

Comment: `.cpp` should work fine for C++. `.C` is usually for `C` code.

Comment: Did you find the documentation of implicit rules?  What have you tried and why did it not work?

Comment: @juanchopanza No. `.C` is for C++ too. `.c` is for C.

Comment: @H2CO3 OK, my bad. But `.cpp` should work for C++ out of the box.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, that's right.

Comment: @DavidGrayson, I found it on http://www.oldlinux.org/Linux.old/Ref-docs/manual%20make/make_10.html#SEC95

Comment: @H2CO3: Using `.C` for C++ source files is problematic on systems with case-insensitive file systems.

Comment: @KeithThompson Sure, and neither do I encourage it. I generally prefer `.cpp`.

Comment: @Zhen That link is 13 years old.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin, I notice today :), but C++ is ~30 years old ...

Comment: @Zhen Hope you are not using 30-year old C++ documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Catalogue of Implicit Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules):

> Compiling C++ programs
>
> n.o is made automatically from n.cc, n.cpp, or n.C with a recipe of the form ‘$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c’. We encourage you to use the suffix ‘.cc’ for C++ source files instead of ‘.C’.

Comment: Ok, I see the problem, I looked on an old doc page. Now .cpp is also used.

Comment: As of today some of the first google results still point to old doc pages.

Answer (score 0):

This is from [GNU make docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rules).

> ‘%’ in a prerequisite of a pattern rule stands for the same stem that
>   was matched by the ‘%’ in the target. In order for the pattern rule to
>   apply, its target pattern must match the file name under consideration
>   and all of its prerequisites (after pattern substitution) must name
>   files that exist or can be made. These files become prerequisites of
>   the target. Thus, a rule of the form
>
> ```
>  %.o : %.c ; recipe...
> ```
>
> specifies how to make a file n.o, with another file n.c as its
>   prerequisite, provided that n.c exists or can be made.

So you could try something similar to

```
%.o : %.cpp %.hpp
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $@
```

Comment: Ok, I see the problem, I looked on an old doc page. Now .cpp is also used.

Comment: Not sure why it refers to some possibly outdated copy of the original GNU make documentation. If you just google for "gnu make manual" the original up-to-date documentation comes up as the first result.